# When applying a bevel on 3 faces, converging at 1 point, the angle is pressed inward

Tags: modeling, objects, interface, edit-mode, bevel

When applying a bevel on 3 faces, converging at 1 point, the angle is pressed inward

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Yes, this is how the bevel "profile" value works.

Comment: Given that my answer didn't solve your problem, can you please add your blend file to your question? (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your bevel settings or share your file by following @MartyFouts suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The shape the bevel takes is controlled by the **Shape** parameter of the Bevel options.  If Shape is < .5 you get an inward (concave) bevel.  If Shape is > .5 you get an outward (convex) bevel.

When you finish the bevel operation there will be a little box in the lower corner of the 3D window. (This will disappear as soon as you do any other operation.)

[image: bevel options]

If you click the triangle it it will expand to something like this:

[image: bevel options]

I suspect that if you look at the Shape field in your options will have a value less than .5.  To get the usual rounded profile, just set the value to .5

Here are a couple of examples with a simple bevel:

.1:

[image: bevel shape set to .1]

.5:

[image: bevel shape set to .5]

.9:

[image: bevel shape set to .9]

When you set the Shape value, blender remembers it and uses the same value the next time you bevel.

Note:  This does depend on your face normals being correct.  You should select all of your faces and compute normals. (SHIFT-N).  Also, if you have bad geometry it won't work, so make sure that there are no duplicate vertices.  (Select all vertices and merge by distance.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the shape parameter is 0.5 and 
increasing or decreasing this parameter doesn't change anything in the object..